# Нумерация строк в ексель

Tags: excel

Подскажите кто знает, как пронумеровать строки в екселе?
Образец:

---

1

---

1

---

2

---

2

---

3

---

3

Comment: В экселе строки уже пронумерованы, Вы их не можете переопеделить, поскольку они же являются координатами ячеек. Все что Вы можете сделать, это добавить еще один столбец в котором Вы определите свои порядковые номера

Comment: Вот именно этот столбец мне и нужно пронумеровать...

Answer (score 2):

Вариант1. В А1 формулу и протянуть вниз:

```
=ЦЕЛОЕ(СТРОКА(A2)/2)
```

Вариант2.
В первых двух ячейках записать единицу, в третьей:

```
=A1+1
```

и протянуть формулу вниз